# Setting Listbox Count Criteria across multiple listboxes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a tool which I am building in excel for an end user to produce an interview form for a job interview, in order to achieve this I have built a series of questoins which determine the criteria of skills needed for the role, and those skills translate to questions which relate to those skills.  The job interview questions selected are limited to 5 at a time.

I have some code which keeps a track of how many Listbox selections are selected in a single listbox, unfortunately due to a UX issue, we have had to re-design the interface.  I have had to produce multiple user forms with their own listbox, and each listbox produces its list by a dynamic named range linked to pivottable criteria.  Does anybody have an idea of how to track selections from multiple listboxes?  The current code below worked for a single listbox.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
Dim counter         As Integer
Dim selectedCount   As Integer

selectedCount = 0

For counter = 1 To ListBox1.ListCount Step 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(counter - 1) = True Then
        selectedCount = selectedCount + 1
    End If
Next counter

If selectedCount >= 6 Then
    ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListIndex) = False
    MsgBox "Pick 5 questions only", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Retry:"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are your listboxes spread across multiple Userforms?

Comment: Yes they are, I have them spread across 6 userforms, but they are all named "Listbox1"

Comment: Can you reference them using the name of the object that they sit on: form1.ListBox1, form2.Listbox1, etc.

Comment: Thank you for that, I rewrote the code to do exactly what you said, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to rewrite this so that it works across multiple listboxes located in different userforms, I put this code in all the userforms which contained the listboxes and it works.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
Dim counter1 As Integer, counter2 As Integer, counter3 As Integer, counter4 As Integer, counter5 As Integer, counter6 As Integer, selectedCount As Integer
selectedCount = 0

For counter = 1 To FirstQuestion.ListBox1.ListCount Step 1
    If FirstQuestion.ListBox1.Selected(counter - 1) = True Then
        selectedCount = selectedCount + 1
        If selectedCount >= 6 Then
            FirstQuestion.ListBox1.Selected(FirstQuestion.ListBox1.ListIndex) = False
            MsgBox "Pick 5 questions only", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Retry:"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next counter

For counter2 = 1 To SecondQuestion.ListBox1.ListCount Step 1
    If SecondQuestion.ListBox1.Selected(counter2 - 1) = True Then
        selectedCount = selectedCount + 1
        If selectedCount >= 6 Then
            SecondQuestion.ListBox1.Selected(SecondQuestion.ListBox1.ListIndex) = False
            MsgBox "Pick 5 questions only", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Retry:"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next counter2

For counter3 = 1 To ThirdQuestion.ListBox1.ListCount Step 1
    If ThirdQuestion.ListBox1.Selected(counter3 - 1) = True Then
        selectedCount = selectedCount + 1
        If selectedCount >= 6 Then
            ThirdQuestion.ListBox1.Selected(ThirdQuestion.ListBox1.ListIndex) = False
            MsgBox "Pick 5 questions only", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Retry:"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next counter3

For counter4 = 1 To FourthQuestion.ListBox1.ListCount Step 1
    If FourthQuestion.ListBox1.Selected(counter4 - 1) = True Then
        selectedCount = selectedCount + 1
        If selectedCount >= 6 Then
            FourthQuestion.ListBox1.Selected(FourthQuestion.ListBox1.ListIndex) = False
            MsgBox "Pick 5 questions only", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Retry:"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next counter4

For counter5 = 1 To FifthQuestion.ListBox1.ListCount Step 1
    If FifthQuestion.ListBox1.Selected(counter5 - 1) = True Then
        selectedCount = selectedCount + 1
        If selectedCount >= 6 Then
            FifthQuestion.ListBox1.Selected(FifthQuestion.ListBox1.ListIndex) = False
            MsgBox "Pick 5 questions only", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Retry:"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next counter5

For counter6 = 1 To SixthQuestion.ListBox1.ListCount Step 1
    If SixthQuestion.ListBox1.Selected(counter6 - 1) = True Then
        selectedCount = selectedCount + 1
        If selectedCount >= 6 Then
            SixthQuestion.ListBox1.Selected(SixthQuestion.ListBox1.ListIndex) = False
            MsgBox "Pick 5 questions only", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Retry:"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next counter6
End Sub
```